# HTML5: Canvas not drawing anything

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am learning HTML5. I am trying to put a canvas in my website and draw stuff on it. But the canvas remains blank. I ran the code in firefox, chrome and IE but the canvas is blank in all the browsers. Am I doing something wrong?

**HTML file:-**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>RAMEN</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ramenStyle.css">
        <script src="mainScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main_div">
            <header id="main_header">
                <h1>RAMEN</h1>
            </header>
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>about</li>
                    <li>history</li>
                    <li>availability</li>
                    <li>flavors</li>
                    <li>worldwide</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="sub_div">
                <section id="main_section">
                    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
                    </canvas>
                    <article id="article1">
                        <header>
                            <hgroup>
                                <h4>About Ramen</h4>
                            </hgroup>
                        </header>
                        <p id="about">
                            Ramen is a Japanese noodle soup dish. It consists of Chinese-style wheat noodles served in a meat- or (occasionally) fish-based broth, often flavored with soy sauce or miso, and uses toppings such as sliced pork, dried seaweed, kamaboko, and green onions. Nearly every region in Japan has its own variation of ramen, from the tonkotsu (pork bone broth) ramen of Kyushu to the miso ramen of Hokkaido.
                        </p>
                        <footer>
                            -wikipedia
                        </footer>
                    </article id="article2">
                    <article>
                        <header>
                            <hgroup>
                                <h4>History of Ramen</h4>
                            </hgroup>
                        </header>
                        <p id="history">
                            The origin of ramen is unclear. Some sources say it is of Chinese origin.Other sources say it was invented in Japan in the early 20th century. The name ramen is the Japanese pronunciation of the Chinese lamian. Until the 1950s, ramen was called shina soba, literally "Chinese soba") but today chūka soba, also meaning "Chinese soba") or just Ramen are more common, as the word (shina, meaning "China") has acquired a pejorative connotation.
                        </p>
                        <footer>
                            -wikipedia
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <aside id="side">
                    <h3>News</h3>
                    <p>
                        Pictures of Ramen coming soon!
                    </p>
                </aside>
            </div>
            <footer id="main_footer">
                Copyright Raj 2015 (rkjha3396@gmail.com)
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

**Javascript File**:-

```
    function f()
{
    var x=document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas=x.getContent('2d');
    canvas.fillRect(10,10,100,200);
    canvas.shadowOffsetX=4;
    canvas.shadowOffsetY=4;
    canvas.shadowBlur=6;
    canvas.shadowColor='rgba(0,0,255,.5)';
    canvas.font="bold 36px Tahoma";
    canvas.textAlign="end";
    canvas.fillText("Ramen noodles super good!", 300, 100);
}
window.addEventListener("load", f, false);
```

Comment: do you get any errors? check your console

Comment: On chrome ctrl+shift+I. Go to console tab and search for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's

```
x.getContext('2d');
```

not

```
x.getContent('2d');
```

```js
 function f() {
   console.log('x');
   var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
   canvas = x.getContext('2d');
   canvas.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 200);
   canvas.shadowOffsetX = 4;
   canvas.shadowOffsetY = 4;
   canvas.shadowBlur = 6;
   canvas.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,255,.5)';
   canvas.font = "bold 36px Tahoma";
   canvas.textAlign = "end";
   canvas.fillText("Ramen noodles super good!", 300, 100);
 }
 window.addEventListener("load", f, false);
```

```html
<div id="main_div">
  <header id="main_header">
    <h1>RAMEN</h1>

  </header>
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>history</li>
      <li>availability</li>
      <li>flavors</li>
      <li>worldwide</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="sub_div">
    <section id="main_section">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
      <article id="article1">
        <header>
          <hgroup>
            <h4>About Ramen</h4>

          </hgroup>
        </header>
        <p id="about">Ramen is a Japanese noodle soup dish. It consists of Chinese-style wheat noodles served in a meat- or (occasionally) fish-based broth, often flavored with soy sauce or miso, and uses toppings such as sliced pork, dried seaweed, kamaboko, and green
          onions. Nearly every region in Japan has its own variation of ramen, from the tonkotsu (pork bone broth) ramen of Kyushu to the miso ramen of Hokkaido.</p>
        <footer>-wikipedia</footer>
      </article id="article2">
      <article>
        <header>
          <hgroup>
            <h4>History of Ramen</h4>

          </hgroup>
        </header>
        <p id="history">The origin of ramen is unclear. Some sources say it is of Chinese origin.Other sources say it was invented in Japan in the early 20th century. The name ramen is the Japanese pronunciation of the Chinese lamian. Until the 1950s, ramen was called
          shina soba, literally "Chinese soba") but today chūka soba, also meaning "Chinese soba") or just Ramen are more common, as the word (shina, meaning "China") has acquired a pejorative connotation.</p>
        <footer>-wikipedia</footer>
      </article>
    </section>
    <aside id="side">
      <h3>News</h3>

      <p>Pictures of Ramen coming soon!</p>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <footer id="main_footer">Copyright Raj 2015 (rkjha3396@gmail.com)</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I call a "typo". There is a close reason about it, since it's unlikely that anybody will find it useful in future.

Comment: @Kaiido should I delete the question?

Comment: I'm not sure... In your case I would do so.

Comment: @Kaiido Before posting the question I tried my very best to find the problem but I couldn't. I am new to this so I didn't know it will be 'context' and not 'content' lol. I think I won't delete the question since I want to give points to the j08691 for solving my problem.

Comment: @Raj. While it's kind of you to want to give points to the answerer, IMHO, you might want to delete your question because it will mislead future searchers to a question that involves a typo rather than a useful Q&A.

Comment: @markE I tried to delete the question but it isn't deleting. An error message says the question has answers and cannot be deleted.

Comment: @Raj. First uncheck the green checkmark and then you should be able to delete the question. ;-)

Comment: @markE - just an FYI, the OP can't delete the question once it has answers, even if they don't accept an answer. At this point only a mod or enough delete votes will close it.

Comment: @j08691. Oh well...did you alert the moderators to delete this typo-only question?